# Custom map on `Array`

Tags: ruby, functional-programming, null, extension-methods

I have the following problem:

> Given an `Array`, apply a certain method `x` to each `Array` element (yielding a new `Array`), with the restriction that array elements which are `nil`, should be mapped to some default value. Method and default element are parameters. Example:
>
> Array: `['abc',nil,'defg']`
>
> Method: `:size`
>
> Default element: `-1`
>
> Expected result: `[3, -1, 4]`

I implemented this by adding a method `map_with` to the `Array` class:

```
class Array
  def map_with(accessor, default_value=nil)
    map {|e| e.nil? ? default_value : e.send(accessor) }
  end
end

['abc',nil,'defg'].map_with(:size, -1)
```

I'm looking for an improvement of my current solution. Can the solution be improved in the following sense?

- Provide the same result with simpler code
- Make the function more flexible (more generally useful) by not adding too much code

Comment: This method is concise enough. I'd suggest move it to `Enumerable` thus it can be applied to sets, queues and so on.

Comment: What is correct behaviour if object dont have method `size` ?

Comment: this question must be moved into code review network

Comment: What do you mean by more general/flexible?

Comment: Your code is already concise. By "**by not** adding too much code", do you mean "**without** adding too much code"?

Comment: @LukasBaliak: To throw an exception (it's the same if you apply a method to an object which doesn't support it).

Comment: @sawa: It means that is doing more than before. For example, Aetherus suggested to move it from `Array` to `Enumerable`. This is a simple and efficient way to make it more general (it can be applied to more than just arrays).

Answer (score 3):

My implementation is very similar to yours, with only a few small tweaks:

```
module Enumerable
  def map_with(accessor, default_value: nil)
    map { |e| e.respond_to?(accessor) ? e.send(accessor) : default_value }
  end
end
```

- Use `Enumerable`, not `Array`, so that the method can be applied to other objects such as instances of `Hash`, `Set`, etc.
- Use `respond_to?` rather than a type-check against `nil`, for better duck-typing robustness.
- Use a named parameter, for improved code clarity.

Comment: That is a method with a different feature.

Comment: Yes, it is. But I consider this to be a more "correct" implementation than simply checking for `nil`.

Comment: Your method is *completely* different: e.g. the OP's method `[1, nil, 2].map_with(:to_s, 'Not available') # => ['1', 'Not available', '2']` and your method `[1, nil, 2].map_with(:to_s, 'Not available') # => ['1', '', '2']`. This completely subverts the whole purpose of the method, namely avoiding strange corner cases with `nil` values. (Also: `Enumerable` is a module, not a class.)

Comment: `This completely subverts the whole purpose of the method, namely avoiding strange corner cases with nil values` --- Debatable.... OP never actually stated the intended use case for the method. What happens if OP tries something like `["foo", "bar", 123].map_with(:reverse)`? I'd need more context to know which behaviour is more desirable.

Comment: It is correct, that @TomLord solved a somewhat different problem than I have stated, but it is close enough to let me rethink my implementation. The difference is mainly in accessors, which are understood by `NilClass` (such as `to_s`), and in my concrete application, it seems that either solution would work.

Answer (score 2):

#### Function Wrapping

Here is an alternative implementation, just for contrast with the other solutions.  It needs a little work to be more robust, but the concept is clear.

This version wraps the target method with a new method that checks the arguments.  If all are nil then the default value is returned, otherwise the arguments are passed to the inner method.  This approach's benefits include being purely functional and not being limited to just mapping; it could be used on any method.  The disadvantage is that usage is somewhat ugly and not as ruby-like as one might wish.

```
# Wrap function in a new function that checks for nil arguments
# If arguments are nil, return default value, otherwise return result
# of original function
def apply_default(default, function)
  fn = function.to_proc
  Proc.new { |*args| args.all?(&:nil?) ? default : fn.call(*args) }
end

a = ['abc', nil, 'defg']

# Usage Examples:
puts '====1===='
f = apply_default(-1, :size)
puts a.map(&f)

puts '====2===='
puts a.map(&apply_default(-1, :size))

puts '====3===='
puts a.map { |e| apply_default(-1, :size).call(e) }
```